# Programmatically add Pivot Items

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

I want to display a list of photos in a Pivot Control, so I have this xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="DiaporamaPivot">
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

and in the code behind I do :

```
    public Diaporama()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PivotItem p = new PivotItem();
        Image     i = new Image();

        i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/image.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        p.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -2);

        DiaporamaPivot.Items.Add(i);
    }
```

Any idea why I get an exception

Comment: I found my bug. I add the Image i to the Pivot Control, not the PivotItem p. Now I need to add the Image in my PivotItem. Anyone knows ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are adding `i` (`Image`) to `Pivot`. Instead, add `i` to `p` and then, add `p` (`PivotItem`) to `Pivot`.

```
public Diaporama()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PivotItem p = new PivotItem();
    Image     i = new Image();

    i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/image.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    p.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -2);

    p.Content = i;
    DiaporamaPivot.Items.Add(p);
}
```