# How to programmatically create PivotItems to add to a PivotView?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivotviewer

I am creating an RSS reader and would like to create `PivotItem`s for RSS the user has.

I know that I'll be passing in the number of items into the PivotView so I can create the number of items upon creation.

Does anyone know how I would go about this programmatically?

Comment: You might be interesting in adding items from c sharp file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439337/programmatically-add-pivot-items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) pattern.

You could create a view model class for the subscriptions and add them to an ObservableCollection. You then just need to bind the Pivots ItemsSource property to the collection:

```
        <controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subscriptions}">
            <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:PivotItem Header="{Binding Path=DisplayName}">
                        <Listbox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                            ...
                            ...
                        </ListBox>
                    </controls:PivotItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: ill try this and Roman suggestion tonight and let u know how it works out