# How to add Tabs dynamically in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am generating a random number between 1 and 10. Based on that number, I want to display tab bars. If the number is `1`, I want to display one tab. If it is `2`, display 2 tab bars simultaneously, etc.. How can I do this? Can anyone suggest an idea for that ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about adding PivotItems into Pivot. Take a look at [Programmatically add Pivot Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439337/programmatically-add-pivot-items) and [How to programmatically create PivotItems to add to a PivotView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133994/how-to-programmatically-create-pivotitems-to-add-to-a-pivotview)