# How to create Pivot and Pivot Items in Windows Phone 8.1 in code?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to create Pivot and Pivot Items in Windows Phone 8.1 in code?

Not in XAML, but with code.

Or give me some msdn page i simply overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could create a `Pivot` through code, but what you can do is to create `Pivot Items` dynamically.

```
 PivotItem p = new PivotItem();use the object p to add content
```

Sample: [Programmatically add Pivot Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439337/)

[MSDN sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Dynamic-Items-to-Pivots-3876aa54/sourcecode?fileId=49879&pathId=298223712)